# Javascript function is not defined, ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, html

I'm just trying to execute an **Ajax request** but instead end up having a **ReferenceError: getData is not defined** on Console. And this piece of code worked fine 6 months back or so. I've already referred some previously asked questions but no good.

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language = "text/javascript"> 
  var XMLHttpRequestObject = false; 
       if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
   XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
 } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { 
   XMLHttpRequestObject = new  
     ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
 } 
 function getData(dataSource, divID)  
 {  
   if(XMLHttpRequestObject) { 
     var obj = document.getElementById(divID);  
     XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", dataSource);  
     XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function()  
     {  
       if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 &&  
         XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) {  
           obj.innerHTML = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;  
       }  
     }  
     XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null);  
   } 
 } 
</script> 
</head>
<body>

<form> 
  <input type = "button" value = "Fetch the message"  
    onclick = "getData('data.txt', 'targetDiv')">  
</form> 

<div id="targetDiv"> 
  <p>The fetched message will appear here.</p>  
</div>  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What browser are you using and what is your full error message (with call stack if provided)?

Comment: **Chrome** : Uncaught ReferenceError: getData is not defined and **firefox** : Exception : getData is not defined

Comment: @SurrealDreams Not everybody likes jQuery, that's not what the OP is asking about...

Comment: it's not what Javascript can't do, it's for learning purpose. Why isn't this working...?

Comment: @raaaz You're not showing us everything. If I paste your code onto http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/933VJ/, it does not throw the error you mentioned

Comment: @JuanMendes it is accessing a **data.txt** file through AJAX request, which is in same directory. so JSFiddle can't run it, as it don't have the **.txt** file.

Comment: I know, but it's actually trying to fetch the file, it's not getting an error trying to call `getData()`. However [Nathan figured it out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24022036/227299).

Comment: @SurrealDreams That's not why you didn't post it as an answer, it's because saying use jQuery is not an answer to the question at all. You're just pushing for a library. Common (observed) etiquette at SO is not to use jQuery unless the OP asked for it, or if it would simplify the OP's code a lot. In this case, it has nothing, nothing at all to do with what the OP is asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your browser doesn't know what language `"text/javascript"` is.  It only knows the language `"javascript"` and the MIME-type `"text/javascript"`.  You're mixing the two up.

You could either change it to `language="javascript"` or `type="text/javascript"`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

`language` is an outdated attribute anyway; `type` is more modern.

Comment: It is indeed the problem... http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/933VJ/1/ Modern browsers assume `type="text/javascript"` so you can also leave it out http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/933VJ/3/

Comment: And we have a winner here! Nice observation, Nathan.